# asio::thread_pool + std::promise — почему-то много VSZ

Tags: c++, память, boost

Есть такой простой пример, в котором происходит использование пула на 70 потоков и создание в каждом `std::promise`:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

constexpr const int size = 70;
boost::asio::thread_pool tp{size};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int total_run = 1;
    if (argc > 1)
       total_run = atoi(argv[1]);
    for (int i = 0; i < total_run; ++i) {
       boost::asio::post(tp, [] () {
          std::promise<void> voidPromise;
          std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(60));
       });
    }
    tp.join();
}
```

Компилирую и запускаю: 
`g++ bad.cpp -o bad -lboost_system -lpthread && ./bad 1000`

Проверяю VSZ:
`ps -o vsz= -p 4142`

Результат: 4708236, то есть около 4.5 гигабайт! И это всего на 70 потоков, в которых по сути ничего не происходит.

Если убрать строку с `std::promise`, то получается намного лучше, а именно 579448.

Почему так происходит? Нормально ли это? Как можно это исправить (уменьшить VSZ) ?

**Обновление**

Версия gcc 8.3.0, boost — 1.69.0

Comment: Что такое VSZ в этом контексте, какого значения вы ожидаете и почему? Если убрать создание promise, то это радикально улучшает ситуацию? Версия компилятора и буста нигде не указана, сборка без аргументов, контролирующих стандарт и оптимизацию сомнительна. Также в примере явно не хватает надлежащих заголовочных файлов.

Comment: @VTT единственное более или менее справедливое замечание — про версии, добавил их в вопрос. Как узнать VSZ, как отсутствие promise влияет на него, написано в вопросе, прошу читать вопрос перед написанием комментария. Почему нельзя собирать без оптимизации, тоже неясно. И у меня нормально собралось и без «надлежащих» заголовочных файлов...

Comment: @VTT `vsz=` у ps - это объем захваченной процессом виртуальной памяти. Вообще с эим кодом происходит имменно это, проверил на boost 1.68. Что-то тут неправильно. Единственное что могу сказать - на объем памяти больше число запросов влияет на число потоков в пуле.

Comment: у меня под рукой буст только 1.65,так что проверить что там не могу, но я бы предложил `ltrace`'ом посмотреть, сколько стека boost выдаёт потокам... а также, сколько потоков реально запускается... ну и думаю всем и так понятно, что расход виртуальной памяти ­— не самая критичная вещь...